# SharePoint IRM permisison caching

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, irm

Today I tried this case

- User 1 has Contribute permission, User 2 has Read permission
- User 1 upload document to IRM enabled Document Library
- User 2 download that document, open in Word and has View only permission
- Change permission of User 2 to Contribute
- User 2 re-download the document and still have View only permission

So is this an expected outcome or I did anything wrong with IRM setup ?